# Wrapping up Elements with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I do have a element and its content some where on the page :

```
<div style="padding-bottom:9px; font-size:13px;line-height:25px;">          
  Fine quality, full grain pebble leather 
  <br>
  <div style="line-height: normal; margin-bottom: 6px; ">
     Sophisticated black with detailed accent lining
  </div>
  Tailored satin ribbon release pull-strap
  <br>
  Slim back pocket for an ID card or money
  <br>
  Ultra slim design
  <br>
  Shock-absorbent construction
  <br>
  Additional screen padding
  <br>
  Light and rigid protective layer
  <br>
  Soft velvet lining with light protective layer
  <br>
  <div style="line-height: normal; margin-bottom: 6px; ">
     Thinner and more streamlined than the Eléga Pouch
  </div>
  Sena high-quality handmade craftsmanship<br>      
</div>
```

What I want to is convert the content above to below with jQuery *(I tried different ways but after all I kinda lost)*

```
<div style="padding-bottom:9px; font-size:13px;line-height:25px;">            
  <div style="line-height: normal; margin-bottom: 6px;">
      Fine quality, full grain pebble leather
  </div>
  <br/>
  <div style="line-height: normal; margin-bottom: 6px; ">
     Sophisticated black with detailed accent lining
  </div>
  <br/>
  <div style="line-height: normal; margin-bottom: 6px; ">
     Tailored satin ribbon release pull-strap
  </div>
  <br/>
  <div style="line-height: normal; margin-bottom: 6px; ">
     Slim back pocket for an ID card or money
  </div>
  <br/>
  <div style="line-height: normal; margin-bottom: 6px; ">
     Tailored satin ribbon release pull-strap
  </div>
  <br/>
   ...
   ...
   ...      
</div>
```

Can you help me a little bit.

Thanks.

Comment: Can't any one offer a solution ? I tried but things mixed up a little bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I was looking for :

```
jQuery("div").filter(lineHeight).contents(nonElementNodes).wrap("<div style='margin-bottom:9px;line-height:normal;margin-top:4px'>");

jQuery("div").filter(lineHeight).find("br").remove();

function lineHeight() {
  return this.style.lineHeight == "25px";
}

function nonElementNodes() {
  return this.nodeType !== 1 || this.tagName !== 'BR';
}
```

[**Source**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2060169/jquery-code-is-working-on-google-chrome-but-not-firefox-ie-and-even-safari/2060266#2060266)

Answer (score 1):

Call me old fashioned but converting markup like that (esp something like `<br>` to `<br/>`) is something that should be done in the original file, not with jQuery after it's been sent and rendered by the browser.

I think you'll be really hard-pressed to do this without modifying the original code since you don't have spans or anything to query on.

Comment: Actually it is not my code, there is a web site and it is totally static and there are a lot of pages include such a structure and I am looking for the easiest way to change the content :)

Comment: I'd *really* recommend going through the old static HTML files and cleaning them up (you might be able to find a script to help batch that). Using jQuery on the client side to try to clean it up is just making an even bigger mess.