# jQuery Code is working on Google Chrome but not Firefox,IE and even Safari

Tags: jquery, firefox, google-chrome

I wrote this code and it is working nicely in Google Chrome but when it comes to Firefox and other major browsers, it is not even changing a little bit thing :

```
jQuery("div[style*='line-height:25px']").contents(":not(nodeType!='1',br)").wrap("<div style='margin-bottom:9px;line-height:normal;margin-top:4px'>");
jQuery("div[style*='line-height:25px'] br").remove();
```

It may look a bit weird but it is the thing I want to solve a really frustrating problem, so anyways let me give you the specifications about the system :

- jQuery 1.3.2 with `noConflict()` method to avoid conflicts with prototype `$`
- Scriptaculous 1.7.1_beta3
- Prototype 1.5.1
- And yeah I am using `jQuery(document).ready()` function to do things after DOM is ready.

Those are the libraries also embedded on the page.

**For Recommendations:**
I didn't develop this page and other hundred of pages like this one and the problem is they are all static pages and using `shtml` to at least share some common code. But I can't remove any of those libraries because it means I will have to edit a lot of pages and it will cost me weeks. So actually what I am looking is temporary solutions like the one above.

Thanks in advance.

**Partial HTML :**

```
<div style="font-size: 13px; line-height: 25px;">
  <!-- BULLETS MORE -->
  <div style="line-height: normal;">
    Fine quality, full grain pebble leather
  </div>
   Smooth Classic Napa leather construction
  <br />
   Lateral footprint with top access
  <br />
   Durable belt clip
  <br />
   Top flap with snap closure for added security
  <br />
   Soft velvet lining with light protective layer
  <br />
   Bottom push-through cutout for easy Motorola Droid removal
  <br />
   Simple Scandinavian rounded design
  <br />
   Sena craftsmanship and quality
  <br />
</div>
```

Comment: Can you give us the whole HTML output (censoring the content/excluding images where necessary) so we can play with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about rewriting them slightly?

```
jQuery("div").filter(lineHeight).contents(nonElementNodes).wrap("<div style='margin-bottom:9px;line-height:normal;margin-top:4px'>");

jQuery("div").filter(lineHeight).find("br").remove();

function lineHeight() {
  return this.style.lineHeight == "25px";
}

function nonElementNodes() {
  return this.nodeType !== 1 || this.tagName !== 'BR';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your contents selector is setup correctly. You should do something like:

```
jQuery("div[style*='line-height:25px']").contents(":not(br)").filter(function(){return this.nodeType != 1;}).wrap("<div style='margin-bottom:9px;line-height:normal;margin-top:4px'>");
jQuery("div[style*='line-height:25px'] br").remove();
```

Comment: It didn't work either. And `nodeType=1` is allowed to be used withing Selector string. Here is an example : http://tinyurl.com/ycanhl2

Answer (score 0):

Dont use `'` in the selector, just:

```
jQuery("div[style*=line-height:25px]")
```

Comment: Just let you know, it is not the solution because even jQuery recommend to use `'` and it won't work with that way :)

Answer (score 0):

yikes. jquery lets you write some very powerful queries, but it doesnt mean that you should.

if you have control over the html you should add some classes where needed and replace that mess with some class selectors, it will work in all browsers and be faster to boot